# Linear independence of finite field elements and subfields

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a prime power and $n=lm$ an integer with $l,m>1$. We know that the finite field $GF(q^n)$ is a $n$-th dimensional vector space over $GF(q)$, and it is also a $l$-th dimensional vector space over $GF(q^m)$.

Suppose that $S$ is  a set of elements of $GF(q^n)$ which is linearly independent over $GF(q)$. Given that $S$ does not contain any elements of $GF(q^m)$, can we say something about the linear dependence or independence of $S$ over $GF(q^m)$? Are there any conditions on $q,m,n,l$ that would make $S$ linearly independent over $GF(q^m)$ too?

Comment: If 2 or more of the elements of $S$ are in the $q^m$ field, then $S$ won't be independent over the $q^m$ field. Well, that's a start.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I should have been more careful. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking too much. Pick an element $\alpha\in GF(q^m)\setminus GF(q)$ and an element $\beta\in GF(q^n)\setminus GF(q^m)$. Then $\beta$ and $\beta\alpha$ are obviously $\notin GF(q^m)$. They are linearly independent over $GF(q)$ because their ratio $\alpha\notin GF(q)$. Yet they are clearly linearly dependent over $GF(q^m)$.

A related concept that may or may not help you is that of *linearly disjoint* field extensions. Given a field $K$ we say that two extension fields, $L$ and $L'$ (both inside a common bigger field), are linearly disjoint over $K$, if any subset of $L$ that is linearly independent over $K$ remains linearly independent over $L'$ (or equivalently any subset of $L'$ that is linearly independent over $K$ remains linearly independent over $L$.

For $L$ and $L'$ to be linearly disjoint over $K$ it is clearly necessary that $L\cap L'=K$. It can be shown that if $L/K$ and $L'/K$ are both Galois, then this necessary condition is also sufficient. In your case this implies that if (and only if) $\gcd(\ell,m)=1$, then the fields $GF(q^m)$ and $GF(q^\ell)$ are linearly disjoint over $GF(q)$. So in that case elements of $GF(q^m)$ that are inearly independent over $GF(q)$ remain so over $GF(q^\ell)$.

Our study group was once in dire need of basic information about this topic, so I wrote [a quick and dirty intro](http://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf) myself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer, this is helpful.