# Linear Independence of Elements over Binary Finite Fields

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Consider the binary finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$ for some $q$. consider a set of elements $r_i$, $1\leq i \leq m$, in $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$ where $m<2^q$.

*My question:* How to check that elements $r_i$'s are linear linear independence over $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$.

Is there a matrix method such as the method that we use for vectors. In fact, is it true that we consider $r_i$'s as a vector in $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ and construct a matrix by these vectors. In the rest, if determinant of this matrix over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ be non-zero then we conclude that $r_i$'s are linear linear independence over $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$.

There is a [similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750210/linear-independence-of-finite-field-elements-and-subfields) but I can not understand how to apply for my question.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Any two elements of $\Bbb{F}_{2^q}$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb{F}_{2^q}$. They may or may not be linearly independent over a subfield though. Or if you meant vectors, like elements of $(\Bbb{F}_{2^q})^m$ for some $m>1$ you can use determinants like José's answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I appreciate for your comments. My clear question is: I work over $\operatorname{GF}(2^q)$ for $q>7$. In these fields I need to select some elements (at lease $2^{q-1}$) such that these elements be linear independence over$\operatorname{GF}(2^q)$. The first method is this, I calculate all linear combinations of these elements to check is zero or not. I thought that instead of the first method, I can use binary vectors for these elements and construct a binary matrix with these vectors and check singularity of the matrix. Just because of this I asked this question. Thanks again.

Comment: Still very unclear. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two elements of $GF(2^q)$, then the relation $$\alpha\beta+\beta\alpha=0$$ shows that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly dependent over $GF(2^q)$. Either you actually want to study their linear independence over a subfield of $GF(2^q)$, or you are to study the linear indepence of vectors from $(GF(2^q))^m$ when the vectors have $m$ components, each from $GF(2^q) $.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Professor Lahtonen, is it possible to ask you to see *Step 1 in  Algorithm 1* of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38553-7_3).  In fact, I want to apply the Algorithm 1, but its Step 2, confused me.

Comment: It seems clear to me that you are to generate a set of $m$ elements of $GF(2^n)$ such that they are linearly independent over $GF(2)$. If you have any basis of $GF(2^n)$ over $GF(2)$ (such as the monomial basis given by a generator of the field extension) then this is equivalent to selecting $m$ linearly independent vectors from $GF(2)^n$. Use the $n$-tuples of elements of $GF(2)$ as coordinate vectors w.r.t. the basis you had. Observe that you only need $m$ linearly independent vectors. They are just denoted as $x_1,x_2,x_4,x_8,\ldots,x_{2^{m-1}}$ because this helps with the rest.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Based on this post, I made a new post. Maybe you find it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing peculiar about these fields as far as linear independence is concerned. Consider, for instance, the vectors $(1,1,0)$, $(0,1,1)$, and $(1,0,1)$. Are they linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$? In order to know, compute the determinant$$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{vmatrix}.$$In turns out that it is equal to $0$. Therefore, the vectors are linearly dependent (for any $q$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your example,  vectors $(1,1,0)$, $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$ means  elements $\alpha +1$,  $\alpha^2 +\alpha$ and  $\alpha^2 +1$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ that is used to construct $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$. Am I right?

Comment: @user0410 No. $(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1)\in{\mathbb{F}_{2^q}}^3=\mathbb{F}_{2^q}\times\mathbb{F}_{2^q}\times\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$. This has nothing to do with polynomials.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm a little confused. Consider for example $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ that is constructed with $f=x^4+x+1$. Consider $\alpha$ is a root of $f$. Now how to check  elements $\alpha^2 +\alpha$, $\alpha^2 +1$ and $\alpha +1$ are linearly dependent  by matrix method over $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$?

Comment: @user0410 Note that $\alpha^2+\alpha$, $\alpha^2+1$, and $\alpha+1$ are $3$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$. Therefore they **cannot** be linearly independent, by the same reason that, say, $1$, $\pi$ and $\sqrt[3]2$ are **not** linearly independent over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: OP wants to know if they are linearly independent, regarding the field with 16 elements as a vector space over the field with 2 elements. The ground field is the field with two elements.

Comment: Please see Setp 2 of Algorithm 1 of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38553-7_3). In Setp 2, it is mentioned that *Select $m$ linearly indepent elements over $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$*. I think your last comment is not correct.

Comment: @AlfredYerger If you know the answer of my question, please help me.

Comment: @AlfredYerger In that case, yes, they are linearly independent. A basis of $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $(\alpha^3,\alpha^2,\alpha,1)$ and, with respect to that basis, the polyomials mentioned by the OP are $(0,1,1,0)$, $(0,1,0,1)$, and $(0,0,1,1)$. They are linearly independent if and only if the matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$has rank $3$. But it has rank $2$ because if we remove any of the lines, we get a square matrix whose determinant is $0$.

Comment: @user0410 You can just check that $(\alpha^2+\alpha)+(\alpha^2+1)+(\alpha+1)=0$. This is equivalent to what José's answer is saying. Actually, studying determinants can also be turned into a method for finding a linear dependency relation.